# Variables in Play Framework routes

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.4

In Play Framework 1.3.x it was possible to use variables in the [routes file](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/routes):

```
%{ context = play.configuration.getProperty('context', '') }%

# Home page
GET    ${context}         Secure.login
```

However, this approach does not seem to work in Play 2.4.

Is there any possibility to set a variable in the routes file in play 2.4?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know this capability has sadly been ditched, though you might be able to achieve something like it using the [advanced routing](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaRoutingDsl) stuff.

Answer (score 0):

GET         /poperties/:userId/:storeId                 @com.a.controllers.b.c(userId, storeId, propertyType:Int=7)

GET         /poperties1/:userId/:storeId                 @com.a.controllers.b.c(userId, storeId, propertyType:Int=6)

propertyType is a variable.

Comment: This approach only uses variables as part of the url and passes it along. I need to specify a variable (e.g. in the config file) and then use it as part of the url itself. E.g. like a prefix.